# InnoDB automatic actions

Tags: mysql, versioning, innodb

I'm using MySQL and InnoDB. I'm versioning all the table's records - the latest version of the record has a column called 'lv' set to 1 and the previous record for that ID that has an 'lv' column set to 1 has to be set to 0 now that there's a new version. I'm now doing two queries every time I insert a new record (version). Is there a way to make InnoDB do that automatically? Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a trigger?

This is untested, but I think something like this would be possible:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER newversion BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE yourTable SET lv = 0 WHERE lv = 1;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

There could be some mistake in there, as it is a quick type, based on [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) ofcourse :)

Comment: I added AND vid = NEW.vid and after submitting the query through phpmyadmin - i get a timeout. The table is only 7 records so far.

Comment: that doesn't actually work, because MySQL doesn't allow changing the same table with triggers except when you only want to change the modifyable row when you can just set the NEW object to the needed value. This way, it does not propagate another trigger, because it's not part of the trigger - it's part of the SQL query that caused the trigger.